# How to use orderBy for inner fields of object in ng-repeat Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

my object looks like this:

```
$scope.options = [{
      name: 'John',
      phone: '555-1212',
      age: 10,
      descriptions: [{
        "languageId": "EN",
        "description": "b Some description",

      }, {
        "languageId": "DE",
        "description": "b Some description in dutch",

      }]

    },
    {
      name: 'Jimmy',
      phone: '555-1212',
      age: 10,
      descriptions: [{
        "languageId": "EN",
        "description": " d Some description",

      }, {
        "languageId": "DE",
        "description": "d Some description in dutch",

      }]

    },
    {
      name: 'Cris',
      phone: '555-1212',
      age: 10,
      descriptions: [{
        "languageId": "EN",
        "description": "a Some description",

      }, {
        "languageId": "DE",
        "description": "a Some description in dutch",

      }]

    }]
```

I want to sort this according to the field "description" in side the "descriptions",

I'm able to sort this by other fields such as name, phone and age, but not by
description.

```
 <tr ng-repeat="option in options | orderBy:'name':true">
     <td> {{option.name}}</td>
      <td ng-repeat="desc in option.descriptions |filter:{languageId:'EN'} ">{{desc.description}}</td> 


    </tr>
```

Please suggest me a way to sort the data by "description".

Comment: have you tried something like `option.descriptions[0]`?

Comment: description looks same for all

Comment: `<tr ng-repeat="option in options | orderBy:'-descriptions[0].languageId'">`

Comment: @gonzalon I haven't tried option.descriptions[0]

Comment: @Jojo look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32111309/1799129

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ngInit` to prefilter description in given language and then use it for sorting and displaying:

```
<tr ng-repeat="option in options | orderBy:'description'" 
    ng-init="option.description = (option.descriptions | filter:{languageId:'EN'})[0].description">
    <td>{{option.name}}</td>
    <td>{{option.description}}</td>
</tr>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/eyRYqfeJ6ewaJnGReGTB?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom sort that can do the trick, The second argument in orderby can taka a string, function or an array Refer [Angular order By](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.4/docs/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

```
<tr ng-repeat="option in options | orderBy:myCustomSort :true">
     <td> {{option.name}}</td>
     <td ng-repeat="desc in option.descriptions |filter:{languageId:'EN'} ">
          {{desc.description}}
     </td> 
</tr>
```

And your JS I guess you can put a variable which language is currently on, and this should do the trick

```
//inside your controller
$scope.lang = 'EN'; //you can edit this the way you added a filter:'EN'
$scope.myCustomSort = function(opt){
    for(var i=0; i<opt.descriptions.length; i++){
        //written assuming you have one description that is for 'EN'
        //you can sort out the description array first and then return
        if(opt.descriptions[i].languageId === $scope.lang){
            return opt.descriptions[i].description.toUpperCase();
        }
    }
    return '';
}
```

Oh and one more thing your description [2] there is a blank space that was messing and took a long time to figure out why ... `"description": " d Some description",`  The blank will be treated first **rules of  sorting :)

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't it be same as outside ng-repeat

```
<td ng-repeat="desc in option.descriptions | orderBy:'description':true |filter:{languageId:'EN'} ">
```